# show ACF fields on thank you page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have searched everywhere but I was not able to find  a solution.

I want to show ACF Field from product to appear on the thank you page.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution would be to add it to a template with [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a page template for "Thank You" page and use `the_field()` method.

Hope it helps.